# Firebase firestore security rules sharing data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this data structure in firestore where I'm trying to link user to profile then to event. A profile can be shared by multiple users and should be able to access events for that profile.

```
user
    - id
    - email
    - name
    - profilePicUrl

profile
    - id
    - name
    - dateOfBirth
    - owners: [ "user1","user2" ]
    - etc.

event
    - id
    - profileId
    - name
    - startDate
    - endDate
```

I currently have:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == id;
    }
    match /profiles/{id} {
        allow read, write: if ("owners" in resource.data && resource.data.owners != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.owners);
    }
    match /events/{id} {
        allow read, write: if hasAccess(userId, resource) == true;
    }
  }
}

function hasAccess(userId, resource) {
    // Not sure what to put here but basically need
    // to get profiles where user is owner
    // and get events for these profiles
}
```

But not sure what to put in the hasAccess function. Appreciate if someone can guide me.

**UPDATE 2019/10/11**

Somehow I got this to work by using the following rule:

```
    match /events/{id} {
            allow read, write: if (exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(resource.data.profileId)) && 
                                  "owners" in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(resource.data.profileId)).data && 
                                  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(resource.data.profileId)).data.owners != null && 
                                  request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(resource.data.profileId)).data.owners);
        }
```

**UPDATE 2019/10/14**

I have some permission issues with the write so I had to revise it as shown below:

```
match /events/{id} {
  allow read: if ( exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(resource.data.profileId)) 
                     &&   "owners" in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(resource.data.profileId)).data 
                     &&   get(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(resource.data.profileId)).data.owners != null 
                     &&   request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(resource.data.profileId)).data.owners);
  allow write: if ( request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/profiles/$(resource.data.profileId)).data.owners );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is actually not possible with security rules given the existing structure of your data.  This is due to the fact that security rules can't perform queries against collections.  The only thing you can do is `get()` a specific document using its known path in order to read its fields, which isn't going to help you link up documents where you can't build that path.

What you can do instead is duplicate the data required for the rule into each document that needs to be protected.  This means each event document needs to have a copy of each list of owners as a field.  Yes, that is going to be more hassle to keep all the events up to date if the list of owners for an event has to change.